# Two separate delays within a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm animating text on a site so that a class is applied to change its opacity & font size and after a set period the font size class is removed leaving the opacity class on it.

(Font class = expanderFade, Opacity class = serviceDisplay)

This all works fine but I need to set up a way so that once the animation is finished (There is 13 separate items being faded) the serviceDisplay class will be removed from the element resulting in it being hidden again before the animation loops.

Code as is:

```
$('.bannerTexts1').delay(1000).queue(function(){
    $(this).addClass("expanderFade serviceDisplay").clearQueue();
    $('.bannerTexts1').delay(2000).queue(function(){
          $(this).removeClass("expanderFade").clearQueue();
    });
});
```

I have also tried the following:

```
$('.bannerTexts1').delay(1000).queue(function(){
    $(this).addClass("expanderFade serviceDisplay").clearQueue();
    $('.bannerTexts1').delay(2000).queue(function(){
          $(this).removeClass("expanderFade").clearQueue().delay(2000).removeClass('serviceDisplay');
    });
});
```

Which just removed it at the same time as the first class. I have also tried making another function after it in the same structure but just with removing the class and none of the previous adding classes code.

I'm a bit unsure as to how I can have two separate delays to correctly remove both of the classes at different times.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which animation are you talking about? Can you provide jsFiddle so your question/expected behaviour would be clearer? BTW, you have to provide all relevant code in question itself (html markup, CSS, etc...). FYI, there are some specific events regarding CSS transition/animation, more sounds like you should use that

Comment: Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ddqozzu2/

Comment: The CSS will like not show any of the content just due to how its set up for the project, will try to tidy it up to get it showing.

Comment: Easiest way to explain the functionality is that the text is hidden upon load, then after the class is added the font size increases, and the opacity goes from 0 > 1 and is given a colour. After 2 seconds the one of the classes is removed and it is left showing (Due to the serviceDisplay class), the final step is to get that class removed after 20 seconds for example. 

If that makes sense?

Comment: I'm really not sure to understand what is your expected behaviour because your posted code in jsFiddle would need some refactorization. But as a side note, this would be called once all anims are done: `$('p[class^=bannerTexts]').promise().done(function(){
            alert('all anims done!');
        });` So set your logic there. But again, not sure it is what you are looking for  https://jsfiddle.net/ddqozzu2/5/

Comment: Checked your fiddle and it works with what I'm needing to do, I added the remove class function within that and it seems to be doing what I need it to be. Will double check it, sorry for explaining it the best. 

If I need to check more I'll modify the fiddle to have one example.

Comment: Ya, you should always provide minimalistic code to replicate issue, let's say using no more than two items with only relevant code for them, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve